# A term/phrase when we move side by side while singing

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

We move side by side humming or singing. It's a gesture we do when we enjoy or like the act of singing.

This happens to our head when we are not standing.

I want a term/phrase for the action when we move our body or head from side to side. I also doubt - it's not side to side (as we do in saying 'NO'). I may better call it 'tilting'. A tilting of head/body from side to side? I'm not sure!

[Example is this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76XrYbjhWwk) Check the kid. However, he's not shaking his head probably because he's singing. But you get an overall idea.

Comment: The expression you want is *side **to** side*. *Side **by** side* involves two entities, each standing at the side of the other.

Comment: Yes. True. But I saw 'by' as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That kid is *'swaying'* from side to side as he sings.

> [sway](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sway) - Move or cause to move slowly or rhythmically backward and forward or from side to side

Another possibility is to *rock*, which one can do with either his body or his head:

> [rock](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rock#rock-2) -   Move gently to and fro or from side to side

Comment: Nice one. Can we use the same when we do this with our head? +1 for sure!

Comment: It's usually the whole body. I don't think I usually move only my head from side to side while singing or listening to music. But you can use the verb *sway* to describe that motion. *He swayed his head from side to side (or back and forth)*.

Comment: I see. If you want to sway and if you are sitting, the head/torso is the only option! ;)

Comment: Added 'rock'. Like rocking a baby, it's usually done slowly and rhythmically... as is 'swaying'.

Comment: This is indeed new to me. Unfortunately, I can upvote only one time! Thank you. In fact, whenever I'd read the word 'rock' shaking something vigorously would come to my mind!